# Does Docker purge old/unused images?

Tags: linux, docker

Many organizations are using Docker specifically for the advantage of being able to seamlessly roll back deployed software. For instance, given an image called `newapi`, deployment looks like this:

```
# fetch latest
docker pull newapi:latest
# stop old one and terminate it
docker stop -t 10 newapi-container
docker rm -f newapi-container
# start new one
docker run ... newapi:latest
```

If something goes wrong, we can revert back to the previous version like this:

```
docker stop -t 10 newapi-container
docker rm -f newapi-container
docker run ... newapi:0.9.2
```

The problem becomes that over time, our local Docker images index will get *huge*. Does Docker automatically get rid of old, unused images from its local index to save disk space, or do I have to manually manage these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do it for you but you can use the following commands to do it manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Delete all containers
sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q)
# Delete all images
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -q)
```

The documentation relating to the docker rm and rmi commands is here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#rm

The additional commands are standard bash.

Comment: If you can link back to documentation, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: added links to the docker docs and the rest is just shell fun.

Answer (score 2):

Update Sept. 2016 for docker upcoming docker 1.13: [PR 26108](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26108) and [commit 86de7c0](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/86de7c000f5d854051369754ad1769194e8dd5e1) introduce a few new commands to help facilitate visualizing how much space the docker daemon data is taking on disk and allowing for easily cleaning up "unneeded" excess.

[**`docker system prune`**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) will delete ALL dangling data (i.e. In order: containers stopped, volumes without containers and images with no containers). Even unused data, with `-a` option.

You also have:

- [`docker container prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)
- [`docker image prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)
- [`docker network prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/)
- [`docker volume prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/)

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images).